# How to reduce database queries and is it Worth it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, query-optimization

I currently have an app that lists flights from one location to another, its price and other information. I have implemented a search through a drop down list so it only shows flights either from a certain location, to a certain location or from and to a certain location, depending on how the user searches.

```
def index
  @flights = Flight.all

  @flights_source = @flights.select('DISTINCT source') #this line is used for options_from_collection_for_select in view
  @flights_destination = @flights.select('DISTINCT destination') #this line is used for options_from_collection_for_select in view

  if params[:leaving_from].present? && params[:going_to].blank?

     @flights = Flight.where(:source => params[:leaving_from])

  elsif params[:going_to].present? && params[:leaving_from].blank?
     @flights = Flight.where(:destination => params[:going_to]) 

  elsif params[:leaving_from].present? && params[:going_to].present?
     @flights = Flight.where(:source => params[:leaving_from]).where(:destination => params[:going_to])     

  end 


end
```

The problem is every time I want to add another search parameter, for example price, it's going to be another query. Is there a way to take Flight.all and search within the result and make a new hash or array with only the records that match the search terms, instead of doing a new query with select DISTINCT.

The closest thing I could come up with is somehow turning the result of Flight.all into a array[hash] and using that get the results for distinct source and destination. But not sure how to do that.

And finally would it be worth it to do this to reduce the number of database queries?

These are the current queries:

```
Flight Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "flights".* FROM "flights"
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Flight Load (1.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT source FROM "flights"
Flight Load (0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT destination FROM "flights"
```

**EDIT:**

I changed the select distinct to

```
@flights_source = @flights.uniq.pluck(:source)
@flights_destination = @flights.uniq.pluck(:destination)
```

And used options_for_select instead of options_from_collection_for_select in the view. But the queries are still, I think this means I eliminated us much as I can, not sure though.

```
(0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "flights"."source" FROM "flights"
(0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "flights"."destination" FROM "flights"
Request Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests"
Flight Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "flights".* FROM "flights"
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
```

Comment: flights is updated regularly by the users. It goes to the third level in the if statement if the user search using both a leaving from location and going to location. The first two levels are either searching using just leaving_from location or just going_to location.

Comment: The search is working right now, it goes to the third branch when, leaving_from and going_to parameters are passed through instead of just one. They can't type anything, search is done using a drop down list, the list is populated with only airports that are in the database.

Comment: You're right sorry about that its late and my tests were a bit off.  I have updated my code.